# Update EAV attribute value in custom admin module

Tags: attributes, model, eav, bug, custom-attributes

I have a form container with save button . This is the method that the save button call.

```
public function saveAction(){
    $userId = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getId();
    $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($userId);
    $idSetting=$user->getShopsetting_entity_id();
    $setting=Mage::getSingleton('Name_Module/shopSetting')->load($idSetting);

    $setting->setData($this->getRequest()->getParam('shopSetting'));
    $setting->save();

    return $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
```

This method create another element in shopSetting_entity, but I want the attributes value is modified.

I also try using

```
$setting->setAttributeName($shopSetting['attribute_name']);
$setting->save();
```

But in this case Magento add a row in shopSetting_entity_int  with same entity_type_id,attribute_id,store_id,entity_id and does not modify the old one.

(int is the type of attribute_name)

I also try  with

```
$setting->setAttributeName($shopSetting['attribute_name']);
$setting->getResource()->saveAttribute($setting,'attribute_name');
```

But the result is always the same.

In particular case of the method saveAttribute of Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract I note that this method distinguishes between the update and insertion, this is the code:

```
....
 $select = $adapter->select()
                ->from($table, 'value_id')
                ->where($where);
            $origValueId = $adapter->fetchOne($select);

            if ($origValueId === false && ($newValue !== null)) {
                $this->_insertAttribute($object, $attribute, $newValue);
            } elseif ($origValueId !== false && ($newValue !== null)) {
                $this->_updateAttribute($object, $attribute, $origValueId, $newValue);
            } elseif ($origValueId !== false && ($newValue === null)) {
                $adapter->delete($table, $where);
            }
            $this->_processAttributeValues();
            $adapter->commit();
...
```

but _insertAttribute and _updateAttribute call the same method _saveAttribute

```
    protected function _insertAttribute($object, $attribute, $value)
{
    return $this->_saveAttribute($object, $attribute, $value);
}
```

....

```
    protected function _updateAttribute($object, $attribute, $valueId, $value)
{
    return $this->_saveAttribute($object, $attribute, $value);
}
```

maybe there's a bug

Comment: What is the dump of $user->getShopsetting_entity_id()? Can you try $user->getShopsettingEntityId()?

Comment: shopsetting entity_id is a name of a column that I associate to user, through this i can find the current setting. In shopSetting params there are the new values of setting that must take the place of old ones.

Comment: I find that the problem is the setDate method, if i set all attributes individually everithing work fine. But If i don't want do this individually?

Comment: Assuming the values are stored in an associative array with keys that match the column names in the database, you can do a foreach loop. I don't know if setData can handle arrays.

Comment: I discovered that it is not correct either do it individually because magento me add another element in the tables entity_int, entity_decimal, which are tables of attribute type that I am dealing

Comment: Good that you found a solution :) Please post it as an answer to your question.

Comment: I was wrong, if I do it individually i have the same problem in a single type table. _int,  _decimal, _char, _datetime, _text ,etc..

Comment: help me please.

Comment: You can find the answer here
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78369/eav-attribute-update-problem

Answer (score 1):

If you call `setData()` with an array, the *complete* data gets *replaced*, this includes the ID.

So, if the result of `$this->getRequest()->getParam('shopSetting')` does not contain the ID, a new entity is created.

You probably are looking for `addData()` which sets only the attributes that exist in the passed array and leaves the rest as it is.

Comment: Ok, I also try using 
$setting->setAttributeName($shopSetting['attribute_name']);
$setting->save();
But in this case Magento replicate a row in shopSetting_entity_int  with same entity_type_id,attribute_id,store_id,entity_id . 
I have tried in many ways, but Magento only add new row does not modify the old one

Comment: That means, you don't have duplicate entities, but duplicate attribute values for a single entity? I.e. (entity_id, attribute_id, store_id) are the same but (value) is different?

Comment: Yes i have duplicate attribute values for a single entity_id.

Comment: The value is irrelevant in all cases Magento adds another row in the table

Answer (score 0):

I have detected the same problem on one of my custom EAV entity types.

When Magento updates EAV values, it uses an `INSERT INTO` with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to update the data in the eav tables.

An example query to update a value looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `download_entity_varchar` 
(`entity_type_id`,`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`value`)
VALUES (9, 6, 446, 'this is a value')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = VALUES(`value`)
```

The MySQL [documenation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) says:

> If you specify `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY`, MySQL performs an `UPDATE` of the old row.

Comparing my custom table indizes to the indizes of `catalog_product_entity_varchar` I realized that there is one index missing on my table: the unique index over the columns `entity_id`, `attribute_id` and `store_id`.

So I added an unique index to my table after removing all duplicate entries, with this:

```
ALTER TABLE `download_entity_varchar`
ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_DOWNLOAD_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID` 
(`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`)
```

If you want to do it programmatically with an upgrade script (usually the smarter way), you just have to add the following lines and adjust the table name:

```
$table = 'download_entity_varchar';
$fields = ['entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'];
$indexType = Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE;

$indexName = $installer->getIdxName($table, $fields, $indexType);
$installer->getConnection()->addIndex($table, $indexName, $fields, $indexType);
```

This **has to** be done for each value type table, which are

- _entity_char
- _entity_datetime
- _entity_decimal
- _entity_int
- _entity_text
- _entity_varchar

After doing that, the values get updated correctly.

For me it seems to be a bug in Magento, that the unique index is not created in `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::createEntityTables`.

Comment: After creating this answer, I found that there's someone else who answered to a [similar question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78371/31734).