# Eav Attribute update problem

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, eav

I followed this article:
http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-an-eav-based-models-in-magento/

I created the Inchoo Blog module, after the firt time it ran the controller code 
the situation on the database is the following:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
value_id | entity_type_id | attribute_id | store_id | entity_id | value
1        |      10        |     142      |     0    |    1      | Test title
2        |      10        |     143      |     0    |    1      | Zoran
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then I changed the controller, in this way:

```
<?php
class Inchoo_Blog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{

$post = Mage::getModel('inchoo_blog/post')->load(1);
$post->setTitle('Test title2');
$post->setAuthor('Zoran Šalamun2');
$post->save();


}
}

?>
```

I wanted to change the values in the database, but the result was as follows:
[image]

How should I do if I want to update those values and not add more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you should not be able to add the 2 lines for the same attribute_id, store_id and entity_id.
If you can, this means that there is no unique index those fields for your tables.

When creating the attributes tables `inchoo_blog_post_entity_datetime`, `inchoo_blog_post_entity_decimal`, `inchoo_blog_post_entity_int`, `inchoo_blog_post_entity_text`, `inchoo_blog_post_entity_varchar`,  `inchoo_blog_post_entity_char` you need to add this before setting the comment (`->setComment('....');`).

```
    ->addIndex(
        $this->getIdxName(
            array('inchoo_blog/post', 'int'), //`int` is for the int table. for other tables change to `varchar`, `text` and so on
            array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
            Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
        ),
        array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
        array('type' => Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE)
    )
```

As a recommendation for the future, you can create your eav entities using [this free extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/). It takes care of everything. Features and documentation [can be found here](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/wiki)

Comment: Marius, i use:
$installer->installEntities();

I did not use that script

Comment: Marius doesn't work

Comment: There is an error, 
 array('inchoo_blog/post', 'int'), -> array('inchoo_blog/post_entity', 'int')

Comment: [Here's](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78371/31734) another, more verbose, answer to the same problem.